# Какое обучение выбрать?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! Возник такой вопрос. Хочется двигаться дальше, но не знаю как.

Дело вот в чем. Я умею верстать. Не очень хорошо, требуется практика и желательно куратор, который мне скажет где мои ошибки и как их исправить. Плюс, знаю основы JS - типы данных, операторы, функции, замыкания, прототипы.

Вопрос: Что мне сейчас лучше делать? Курсы дорогие. Но в то же самое время не хочется сейчас "толкаться" на месте, пытаясь как-то самостоятельно получить необходимые навыки и знания.

Что подскажете? Вы как учились? Курсы или самостоятельно? Если курсы, то какие посоветуйте? Если не курсы, то какие ресурсы?

Comment: А сколько тебе лет? Лучше всего найти работу в веб разработке :) Пусть стажёром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я ставил себе цель, например сделать калькулятор. Во время работы много чего узнаёшь нового, что-то не понял, ищешь в интернете, задаёшь вопрос на stackoverflow. Очень помог мне канал от 0 до 1: https://m.youtube.com/c/%D0%9E%D1%820%D0%B4%D0%BE1 понятно и наглядно показывает вёрстку, есть ещё и зарубежный канал, не смотрел, но тоже советуют: https://m.youtube.com/c/Bedimcode. И соглашусь с предыдущим советом, лучше всего это стажировка.